# Huge CSV file with timestamps, creating a graph with the number of entries in each month of the year

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a fairly large csv file containing every song I have listend to on spotify since Janurary. The csv file contains the UNIX timestamp, and a text timestamp (formatted as: 19 Dec 2018, 13:19). I would like to produce a graph of the number of songs listend to per month.

I have already imported the CSV file into a pandas dataframe, and converted the text datetime into a pandas datetime:

`scrobbles['text_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(scrobbles['text_timestamp'])`

I have played around with `scrobbles_split_month = [g for n, g in scrobbles.set_index('text_timestamp').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M'))]`
This gives me a dataframe containing 12 dataframes, each one all the songs for each month.
I Then count each record in each dataframe to obtain the number of songs for each month like so:

`month_counts = []
    for idx in range(len(scrobbles_split_month)):
        df = scrobbles_split_month[idx]
        month_counts.append(df['track'].count())`

This gives me an output like so: [11, 309, 698, 1874, 1089, 901, 1193, 3105, 2220, 3065, 3095, 2202] where each record is the songs per month.

What I would like to do is to plot this information on a linegraph using maatplotlib, with the months on the x axis, and the song counts on the y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
month_counts = [11, 309, 698, 1874, 1089, 901, 1193, 3105, 2220, 3065, 3095, 2202]
months = 'January February March April May June July August September October November December'.split()

plt.plot(months, month_counts)
plt.show()
```

Since you already did most of the hard work, all that's left is printing with plt.plot() and plt.show(). Of course, this considers `month_counts` is correctly sorted.

Comment: Yeah this works fine thanks, didnt realise it was that simple.

Answer (score 1):

I made a graph similar to what you're looking for awhile back. If I understand you correctly you'll just need to create a generic date range to use as you x axis. What I did was reindex the dataframe with my monthly aggregations with their corresponding Month/Year datetime values. So something like:

```
# your original code
scrobbles['text_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(scrobbles['text_timestamp'])

month_counts = []
    for idx in range(len(scrobbles_split_month)):
        df = scrobbles_split_month[idx]
        month_counts.append(df['track'].count())

# and then set the index to the time stamp which can be your x var and monthly_counts as # your y var
df.index = scrobbles['text_timestamp']
df['monthly_counts'] = month_counts
```

```

You may want to checkout the pandas method: `resample` and `groupby` which works well with datetime values. Though you'll probably want to transform the original timestamps to just their month/year values along with grouping:

`from datetime import datetime as dt
df.index = pd.Series(df.index).apply(lambda x: dt(x.year, x.month, 1)`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it but something like this should work:

```
scrobbles['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(scrobbles['text_timestamp'])
scrobbles['Month'] = scrobbles['Datetime'].dt.month
groupby_month = scrobbles.groupby('Month')
groupby_month['Datetime'].count().plot()
```